# msysGit un-install runtime error 18:1292 could not call proc

Tags: git

When trying to un-install Git on Windows 7, I received this error message:

"Runtime Error (at 18:1292): Could not call proc."

According to my research, the msysgit team fixed this bug. Yet in this case it is preventing me from un-installing Git.

I tried multiple un-installation methods that I found on StackOverFlow, with no success.

Comment: Maybe update it first, and then try to uninstall it?

Comment: There was a bug introduced into the installer code recently. This has been reported on the msysGit mailing list and a fix applied to the sources. The next version will have it fixed - in the meantime, rmdir /s/q will clear the files if you really have to loose them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this problem here.

You can install the latest version of GIT (currently 1.7.8) over the top of 1.7.7.1-preview, you can then uninstall GIT without a problem.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to uninstall Git-1.7.7.1-preview20111027.exe by deleting all the files in the Git directory (I had already used KillBox.exe to delete the git-cheetah dll in previous attempts) and installing Git-1.7.6-preview20110708.exe. Which I than uninstalled.

Comment: to delete the git-cheetah folder you need to first place privileges for the user to allow him to delete it. Even when I did this with KillBox.exe I had issues uninstalling.

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  You should probably also incorporate patthoyts' comment on the OP.  As for: "I had already used KillBox.exe to delete the git-cheetah dll in previous attempts" - What is KillBox.exe, why do you need it, what did you do with it, and where did you get it?  (I figured out the answers to these after googling for KillBox.exe, but they aren't obvious from the context of your answer). Also, I've used SysInternal's [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) before to kill open file handles.  Is KillBox.exe easier to use/faster for the same task?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the same version only this time follow these instructions given here: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ with the following deference:
On the 5th screen uncheck Additional Icons and Windows Explorer Integration
On the 6th screen instead of "Use git bash only", choose the second option "Run Git from Windows Command Prompt".
I think the exception we were getting was the result of not having the proper path set up in the system environment variables:
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/detail?r=33cc102ca9e3833aec8d3325c698f23791add6f0

Also, FYI:
There is a suggestion here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/13834
to uninstall the Git-1.7.7.1-preview20111027.exe by installing an older version (Git-1.6.2.2-preview20090408.exe) over it. I tried the same, but wouldn't work. Calling unins000 nor uninstalling through the add/remove programs, didn't do the trick.

On a side note, I now understand why a colegue of mine said that he prefers using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial to Git. He said he didn't have to bother with all the exception thrown by cygwin (dealing with windows stuff) and I back him up on this.

Anyway, I hope my comment save some time for u guys.

Cheers!

Comment: Msysgit uses MSys, not Cygwin.  I'm not sure this is a side effect of that decision at all - it is an installer bug.  And it is a problem in this flavor of Git installer, not Git itself.  You might argue that if HG had a native port that didn't require a Posix layer that it might be less prone to bugs, but I personally think that's a bit of a stretch.  Also, hg isn't a drop-in replacement for git at all.  For example, no in-built SVN bridge that I've heard of.  I'd have to have a lot more reasons to switch to convince my whole team to do so :)